# MYSQL: Function to calculate an order total

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL function to calculate the total of a customer's order.

The data is normalized, coming from two different tables. I believe I've gotten the scaler select statement working properly but **am struggling to multiply by the quantity, and aggregate the rows together to return it**.

Here is my query (which is giving me a "not allowed to return a result set from a function" error):

```
delimiter $$
create function calcOrderTotal(id int(10))
returns decimal(10,2)
reads sql data
begin
    declare orderTotal decimal(10,2);
    select itemId, (select itemPrice from item i where oi.itemId = i.itemId), quantity from orderItem oi where orderId = id;
    set orderTotal = sum(itemPrice);
    return (orderTotal);
end $$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need a join:

```
SELECT SUM(itemPrice * quantity)
FROM   item i JOIN orderItem oi USING (itemId)
WHERE  orderId = ?
```

But, if you absolutely must put it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcOrderTotal(id INT(10))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
READS SQL DATA
RETURN (
  SELECT SUM(itemPrice * quantity)
  FROM   item i JOIN orderItem oi USING (itemId)
  WHERE  orderId = id
);
```